# Ionic: $cordovaSocialSharing cannot read property of undefined

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, socialshare

I want to use this plugin: [$cordovaSocialSharing](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/) since it's the only plugin I've found for native social buttons on Ionic...

I get this error when I'm running my code in Chrome console:
"Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined" @ (ng-cordova.js:6715)

I reinstalled ng-Cordova as it says in ngcordova.com and the plugin multiple times but it seems it doesnt' work...I tried in an Android emulator and neither does.

Here my code:
In my controllers.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'ionic-ratings', 'onezone-datepicker', 'ngCordova'])
```

then,

```
.controller('CaravanDetailCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $cordovaSocialSharing, sweetAlert) {
   $scope.socialsharingFacebook = function() {

            $cordovaSocialSharing
                .shareViaFacebook("msg", "img", "url")
                .then(function(result) {
                    SweetAlert.swal({   
                        title: "",   
                        text: "success",   
                        type: "success",   
                        showCancelButton: false,   
                        confirmButtonColor: "rgba(5, 60, 84, 0.8)",   
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",   
                        closeOnConfirm: true 
                    });
                }, function(err) {
                    SweetAlert.swal({   
                        title: "",   
                        text: "sorry",   
                        type: "error",   
                        showCancelButton: false,   
                        confirmButtonColor: "rgba(5, 60, 84, 0.8)",   
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",   
                        closeOnConfirm: true 
                    });
                });
    }
```

}

I tried with this too (in controllers.js):

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   $cordovaSocialSharing
            .shareViaFacebook("msg", "img", "url")
            .then(function(result) {
                SweetAlert.swal({   
                    title: "",   
                    text: "success",   
                    type: "success",   
                    showCancelButton: false,   
                    confirmButtonColor: "rgba(5, 60, 84, 0.8)",   
                    confirmButtonText: "OK",   
                    closeOnConfirm: true 
                });
            }, function(err) {
                SweetAlert.swal({   
                    title: "",   
                    text: "sorry",   
                    type: "error",   
                    showCancelButton: false,   
                    confirmButtonColor: "rgba(5, 60, 84, 0.8)",   
                    confirmButtonText: "OK",   
                    closeOnConfirm: true 
                });
            });
}
```

Any idea how to solve this or alternatively, any idea of another plugin that actually works on Ionic?

Comment: Did you included `ng-cordova.js` and `cordova.js` ?

Comment: ngCordova should be second argument in your app.js, and you should include cordova.js and ng-cordova.min.js files in index.html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use real device, most Cordova plugins are not available in browser.

Detect That Your Application Is Running in Cordova/Phonegap

```
  if (window.cordova) {
     $cordovaSocialSharing
          .shareViaFacebook(message, image, link)
          .then(function(result) {
      // Success!
     }, function(err) {
         // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
     });
  } else {
    console.log('Not a device');
  }
```